# How to create checkbox in c & mingw

Tags: c, mfc, mingw

How can I create a checkbox / radio button / number stepper in c?
I can make a button like this:

```
CreateWindowEx(0, "BUTTON", label, WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD, 10, top, 100, 20, hWndDlg, NULL, hInst, NULL);
```

I'm using mingw to compile. I searched this and found that this is not possible with mingw because it doesn't support MFC?

Also it might be easier to understand what I'm trying to do:

```
void renderOptionsTab (HWND hWndDlg, JSONLinkElement *tab) {
    int top = 35;
    do {
        std::string type = std::string((char *)((JSONObject *)tab->value)->getValue("type"));
        char *label = (char *)((JSONObject *)tab->value)->getValue("label");
        void *value = (char *)((JSONObject *)tab->value)->getValue("value");

        char *forComponent = (char *)((JSONObject *)tab->value)->getValue("for");
        char *idComponent = (char *)((JSONObject *)tab->value)->getValue("id");
        char *group = (char *)((JSONObject *)tab->value)->getValue("group");


        char *display = (char *)((JSONObject *)tab->value)->getValue("display");

        if (type == std::string("checkbox")) {
            CreateWindowEx(0, "Button", label, WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD, 10, top, 100, 20, hWndDlg, NULL, hInst, NULL);
        } else if (type == std::string("br")) {

        } else if (type == std::string("buildID")) {
            CreateWindowEx(0, "Static", VERSION.c_str(), WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD, 10, top, 100, 20, hWndDlg, NULL, hInst, NULL);
        } else if (type == std::string("browse")) {

        } else if (type == std::string("label")) {

        } else if (type == std::string("radio")) {

        } else if (type == std::string("number")) {

        } else if (type == std::string("button")) {
            CreateWindowEx(0, "BUTTON", label, WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD, 10, top, 100, 20, hWndDlg, NULL, hInst, NULL);
        }

        if (display != NULL) {
            if (std::string(display) == std::string("inline")) {
                top -= 30;
            }
        }

        top += 30;
        tab = tab->next;
    } while (tab->next != NULL);
}
```

Button works, have no idea how to solve the rest.

Comment: this is plain WinAPI, and should work with mingw. could you show us how you use CreateWindowEx? (the code around it)

Comment: Umm.. I don't understand, I use it many ways, do you want to know how I created `hWndDlg`?

Comment: Yes, and where/when you create the button. The common way is to create your main window with CreateWindowEx() and add stuff like Buttons in your WindowProcedure on WM_CREATE with CreateWindow().

Comment: Well.. it's a bit more complicated. The window I'm trying to add to was created by `DialogBox(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_DLG_SETTINGS), NULL, reinterpret_cast<DLGPROC>(settingsDlgProc));` in that there is a tab control `CreateWindowEx(0, WC_TABCONTROL, "", WS_CHILD | WS_CLIPSIBLINGS | WS_VISIBLE,  10, 10, rcClient.right - 20, rcClient.bottom - 42, hwndParent, NULL, hInst, NULL);` and I want to add to the `DialogBox` in a response to `case WM_NOTIFY:
   if (((LPNMHDR)lParam)->code == TCN_SELCHANGE) {`

Comment: Oh I'm sorry. I misunderstood your question. You are searching for something like a CheckBox Class.

Comment: yes, sorry if it was unclear

Comment: Don't post screenshots of text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CreateWindowEx(0, "BUTTON", label, WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | BS_CHECKBOX, 10, top, 100, 20, hWndDlg, NULL, hInst, NULL);
```

You just need to add the `BS_CHECKBOX` or `BS_RADIOBUTTON` Style.
See:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775951%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
for a full list of available Styles.

Comment: ohh.. that seems easier than I taught. Thank you! Do you have anything on number steppers? (small textbox with two buttons on the right: up & down)

Comment: Sorry, I haven't found anything about that. I Think you have to build it yourself with an edit control and 2 buttons.